# Programação paralela Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

Estou começando a aprender programação paralela, e estou querendo comparar um programa com single thread com um com multi thread.

O que eu pensei foi fazer um algorítimo bem simples que, em um intervalo de 1 minuto, calculasse a quantidade maior de números primos possíveis, e, me mostrasse o último número primo calculado e a sua posição nos números primos, por exemplo, digamos que fosse o número 23, apareceria o numero 23 e sua posição, no caso 9, pois ele é o 9º número primo.

Utilizei o QtConcurrent para fazer a divisão das threads.

Sem utilizar o paralelismo, o número encontrado foi 117779, na posição 119963. Porém, ao utilizar paralelismo, eu obtive o número 198227, na posição 17934 (posição errada e número errado, esse valor não é primo e o primo anterior tinha posição 17839, bem menor do que a posição mostrada no final). Acredito que eu tenha que usar a biblioteca , mas eu não consigo encontrar um jeito de implementar no meu código.

Abaixo segue o código:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qtconcurrentrun.h>
#include <QFutureSynchronizer>
#include <QThread>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

time_t endwait;

int ehPrimo(int num) {
    int  i;
    for (i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
        if (num%i==0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

void funcThread(QString name, int *p, int *n, int *u){
    while (time (NULL) < endwait){
        if(ehPrimo(*p)) {
            *n = *n + 1;
            *u = *p;
        }
        *p = *p + 2;
        //qDebug() << endl << name << " p"<<*p<<" n"<<*n<<" u"<<*u << "from: " << QThread::currentThread();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int p = 5, n = 2, u=p;
    int seconds = 5;

    endwait = time (NULL) + seconds;

    QFuture<void> t1 = QtConcurrent::run(funcThread, QString("A"), &p,&n,&u);
    QFuture<void> t2 = QtConcurrent::run(funcThread, QString("B"), &p,&n,&u);
    QFuture<void> t3 = QtConcurrent::run(funcThread, QString("C"), &p,&n,&u);
    QFuture<void> t4 = QtConcurrent::run(funcThread, QString("D"), &p,&n,&u);


    t1.waitForFinished();
    t2.waitForFinished();
    t3.waitForFinished();
    t4.waitForFinished();

    cout << "\n\n Encontrou " << n << " primos.";
    cout << "\n\n Ultimo primo: " << u << ".\n\n";



    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, o seu código tenta fazer o cálculo num determinado intervalo de tempo, então acho que é normal a posição variar. Sobre o resultado errado(o numero não ser primo), eu acredito que isso aconteça pq as suas threads estão usando as suas variáveis numa ordem errada porque a sua função está dessincronizada. Isso é chamado de *race condition*.

Quando você "dispara" uma thread nova, você não tem controle sobre ela. Você precisa usar algum recurso pra impedir que ela faça coisas inesperadas como modificar uma variável ao mesmo que outra thread ou em uma ordem diferente da que vc espera.

Eu usei QMutex pra lockar a sua função e o resultado aqui sempre foi um número primo.

```
time_t endwait;
QMutex mutex;

int ehPrimo(int num) {
    for (int i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
        if (num%i==0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

void funcThread(QString name, int *p, int *n, int *u) {
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    while (time (NULL) < endwait){
        if(ehPrimo(*p)) {
            *n = *n + 1;
            *u = *p;
        }
        *p = *p + 2;
    }
}
```

Pesquise sobre sincronização de threads e as class QMutex, QWaitCondition, etc.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html